# Complement of subspace in terms of direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces, direct-sum

Let $U\subset W$ be a vector space. Show that there exists another subspace $V$ such that $W=U\bigoplus V$. What can be a candidate of such subspace?

Comment: Not true in general. You must have forgotten some hypothesis.

Comment: Write a basis for $U$, then complete to a basis of $W$, the extra basis elements you add will span $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a vector space over a field $K$ is a free, hence projective, $K$-module.
Thus the exact sequence
$$O\to U\hookrightarrow W\xrightarrow{\pi} W\diagup U\to O$$
splits, that's there exists a $K$-linear map $\varkappa:W\diagup U\to W$ such that $\pi\circ\varkappa = \mathrm{id}|W\diagup U$.
The image $V=\mathrm{Im}(\varkappa)\subseteq W$ is the required subspace.